# Develop bots for CS:GO

Tags: steam

I'm working on a project where we would like to create a more "intelligent" bot in CS:GO (as a training-bot that you can play against in offline mode). We're currently in the start-up process and there's some initial questions. Would be greatly helpful if anyone can help out with some answers!

After some research there seems to be difficulties developing bots for CS:GO as a third-party-bot developer. Is it only VALVE that develops bots for CS:GO or is it possible for a developer to create a bot in CS:GO? Is anyone here comfortable with developing bots for games such as CS:GO? If so, it would be awesome to get some more in-depth answers about our project.

Comment: the only way I see would be by using some third party softwares that allows you to control the game like if you were a real player (input simulation). Autoit can be good for that, but your projet is kinda against the EULA of Valve, you should pick another game if you want to make a FPS bot.

Comment: @Supamiu I think the question is about singleplayer bots -- bots to play against, not bots that play for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yes, the question is about singleplayer bots, or more like bots that you can train with when playing offline. Sorry, should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're able to change their general difficulty, skill, what they look like, what they sound like and what they buy, you're unable to really change how they work and where they go and what they do. This means that you'd also likely need to hook into the game's code or write your own server software that would be able to modify the bots itself. Note that both of these are *likely* against Valve's TOS.

Files that include variables/code for bot behaviour:

- `/csgo/botprofile.db` - skill variables, voice pitch, buying behaviour
- `/csgo/botprofilecoop.db` - same as above, but for coop
- `/csgo/botchatter.db` - how and when bots talk through the radio

Note that a community member has made [Bot AI Framework for DotA 2](https://github.com/ModDota/Dota2AIFramework). While they no longer share the same engine, you might find it useful for your research.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The framework for DotA 2 is great, it's pretty much exactly what we would like to do with bots for CS:GO.